# Visual Studio auto populate parameters for a meted on hitting space

Tags: visual-studio-2019, resharper

I am having problems getting back my Visual studio settings back how it was before the change.

I had a Resharper installed but I am not sure if that is the feature that belongs to Resharper or VS.

a) I am looking for Visual studio to suggest the right parameters for a method when I click the space in a ().

```
DataAccess.CRUDAsync<XElement>("StoredProcedure", **space**)
```

**space** would give me the parameter that is needed deep to 2 layers for example:

1. CommandTypeEx.StoredProcedure
2. CommandTypeEx.Function
3. CommandTypeEx.Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. That is definitely Resharper's functionality. My Resharper subscription has been expired and I just had to reactivate it.  https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360001214539-How-to-Install-and-Activate-ReSharper-